# How to get props from parent in React Styled Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

In `foo.js` I have:

```
import Bar from "./bar.js"

function Foo() {
    const [myProp, setMyProp] = useState("red");

    return(
        <div>
            <Bar prop={myProp}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

In `bar.js` I have:

```
import styled from "styled-components"

const MyStyledComponent = styled.h1`
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: props.color;
`

function Bar() {
    return(
        <MyStyledComponent/>
    )
}
```

Of course, `color: props.color` doesn't work outside of the function `Bar`. How do I access `Bar`'s `myProp` property without putting `MyStyledComponent` inside the function and sacrificing good practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Bar` needs to consume the props passed to it, and pass them on to children.
2. `MyStyledComponent` needs to correctly consume the passed prop.

Code

```
const MyStyledComponent = styled.h1`
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: ${(props) => props.color};
`;

function Bar({ prop }) {
  return <MyStyledComponent color={prop}>Test</MyStyledComponent>;
}

function Foo() {
  const [myProp, setMyProp] = useState("red");

  return (
    <div>
      <Bar prop={myProp} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit friendly-greider-tjurq]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can [inject props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) into your styled component:

```
const MyStyledComponent = styled.h1`
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: ${props => props.color};
`

function Bar() {
    return(
        <MyStyledComponent color="red" />
    )
}
```